# Returning printf from function in main IO fails to print with putStrLn

Tags: haskell

I want to write a small script which calculates the differences between two timestamps and returns the hours formatted like `hh:mm`. For example:

`./calc-hours 8 32 15 42` should return `7:10h`

Note: I don't really care about edge cases which go from 23:00 to 01:00. The code below may even be wrong still but I have a different problem.

The code I came up with is this:

```hs
import Text.Printf
import System.Environment   
import Data.List  

-- Time in minutes starting from 00:00h
tm h m = h * 60 + m
-- Time difference between two timestamps in minutes
td h1 m1 h2 m2 = (tm h2 m2) - (tm h1 m1)
-- Print time difference formatted in hh:mm format
ptdf (h1:m1:h2:m2:hms) 
  | hms /= [] = printf "usage: calc-hours <h1> <m1> <h2> <m2> %s" (show "test")
  | otherwise = printf "%s:%s until %s:%s => %d:%dh" (show h1) (show m1) (show h2) (show m2) h3 m3
  where 
    d = td h1 m1 h2 m2;
    h3 = div d 60;
    m3 = mod d 60

main = do  
    args <- getArgs
    putStrLn . ptdf args
```

I tested these `tm`, `td` and `ptdf` functions directly with `ghci` and they worked so far. When I compile this little script with `ghc` I get the following error:

```
☁ ghc calc-hours.hs && ./calc-hours 8 32 15 42
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( calc-hours.hs, calc-hours.o )

calc-hours.hs:18:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO b’
                  with actual type ‘a0 -> IO ()’
    • Probable cause: ‘(.)’ is applied to too few arguments
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn . ptdf args
      In the expression:
        do args <- getArgs
           putStrLn . ptdf args
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do args <- getArgs
                 putStrLn . ptdf args
    • Relevant bindings include
        main :: IO b (bound at calc-hours.hs:16:1)
   |
18 |     putStrLn . ptdf args
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Could someone please explain what is going wrong here and how I can fix it? I was under the impression that `ptdf` returns a String or at least something with which `putStrLn` can work with. `:t printf` also does not really point me in any direction.

```
Prelude> :t printf
printf :: PrintfType r => String -> r
```

Comment: 1) Always write types for your functions, so to get better type error messages. 2) `f . g x` means `(f) . (g x)` and composes function `f` with function `g x` -- this is completely different from `f (g x)` which is equivalent to `(f . g) x`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the `printf`, the problem is that your `ptdf args` returns an `PrintfType r => r`. Here in this case, the idea is that this will use `String`. You are writing `putStrLn . ptdf args`, so you are constructing a function, but `putStrLn . ptdf args` should be an `IO a` since `getArgs` is an `IO [String]`.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    ptdf args
```

For your `ptdf` function, you will need to parse the parameters with `read`:

```
ptdf :: [String] -> IO ()
ptdf [h1, m1, h2, m2] = printf "%s:%s until %s:%s => %d:%dh\n" h1 m1 h2 m2 h3 m3
  where d = td (read h1) (read m1) (read h2) (read m2)
        h3 = div d 60
        m3 = mod d 60
ptdf _ = printf "usage: calc-hours <h1> <m1> <h2> <m2> %s\n" "test"
```

or we can let `ptdf` generate a `String`:

```
ptdf :: [String] -> String
ptdf [h1, m1, h2, m2] = printf "%s:%s until %s:%s => %d:%dh" h1 m1 h2 m2 h3 m3
  where d = td (read h1) (read m1) (read h2) (read m2)
        h3 = div d 60
        m3 = mod d 60
ptdf _ = printf "usage: calc-hours <h1> <m1> <h2> <m2> %s" "test"
```

and then print that string with:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    putStrLn (ptdf args)
```